# could not update project configuration java.lang.nullpointerexception

Tags: maven-3

Delete the .settings and .project files from project and update the project and rebuild it.

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: I got the above issue when i was running the tomact server.

Comment: By doing below steps.Delete the .settings and .project files from project and update the project and rebuild it.